# How to monitor memory bandwidth usage under Linux

Tags: java, linux, performance, memory, memory-management

I am currently studying the performance of an **Java** application. This application is launched on a powerful Linux server

- 64 cores (32 * 2)
- 800 Gb memory
- 4 GPU (Tesla K80)

However the performances are not so great.

Once a **huge amount of data** is loaded, the application I am studying is supposed to run **parallelized** computation on it via **GPU** then **CPU**. Finally, it collects the results.

I suppose that the memory bus is a bottleneck of the application. I suppose that the memory bus cannot provide data fast enough to the application *(Maybe I also have cache/cache-stride issues)*

I am looking for a (linux command line) tool in order confirm or refute this hypothesis

Thank you for your help

Comment: Intel vtune amplifier can does in depth analysis.

Comment: I Hope this post can help you:                                                  [http://superuser.com/questions/102005/how-can-i-display-the-memory-usage-of-each-process-if-i-do-a-ps-ef](http://superuser.com/questions/102005/how-can-i-display-the-memory-usage-of-each-process-if-i-do-a-ps-ef)

Comment: This page talk about tool that display the memory usage, i.e. **the memory allocated to the process**. I have a quite good vision of the memory used by the application I am studying, what I am looking for is **the rate/throughput at which my application reads (or is consuming) the memory** allocated to it

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)